# How to import the following file as a dataset?

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering, files-and-directories

Consider a file ['temp.txt'](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vzih1k7z7agd4i/temp.txt?dl=0) ([alternative link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=117JV6-fcXYRjQTpDyZ9FQwYS-FjkipGz)). I am trying to import it as a data-file, i.e. in the form

```
XXX XXX XXX XXX
```

where XXX denotes numbers. However, I am not able to do this. Could you please show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Partition[
  N@Chop@ToExpression@StringReplace[
    "{" <> Import["file_path\temp.txt"] <> "}",
     {"#" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ "\n" -> "", "\t" -> ",", "e+" -> "*^", "e-" -> "*^-"}
  ],
  4
]
```

> {{0.,0.,0.,0.25},{0.5,0.75,1.,1.25},{1.5,1.75,2.,2.25},{2.5,2.75,3.,3.25},{3.5,3.75,4.,4.25},<<449164>>,{0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.}}